# React TS loop through object and get checked value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do I get a get a value from object key when looping through it.
I currently have an object like this:

```
    const [brandState,setBrandState] = useState({
        Brands:{
            NewBalance: false,
            Nike: false,
            Addiddas: false,
            Converse:false,
            UnderArmour:false,
        },
});
```

And I am looping through it rendering checkbox inputs like this:

```
{
  Object.keys(brandState.Brands).map((brand)=>
  <div className="">
  <label htmlFor={brand} className="mr-[10px]">{brand}: </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name={brand} className="cursor-pointer" />
  </div>
  )
  }
```

Everything workouts apart from getting the value (true or false)
I tried setting `checked={brand}` but I get an error saying that brand is a string, I also tried `checked={brandState.Brands.brand}`  however that also gives me an error.
How can I get the value of each key to set as the checked?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to Sherry Hsu's excelent suggestion, you can loop over entries instead of keys:

```
  Object.entries(brandState.Brands).map(([brand, checked])=>
  <div className="">
  <label htmlFor={brand} className="mr-[10px]">{brand}: </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name={brand} className="cursor-pointer" checked={checked}/>
  </div>
  )
```

Comment: I also tried this and getting errors on htmlFor and name : Type '[string, boolean]' is not assignable to type 'string' and checked for : Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'. I think i am doing something wrong with the types any help? thanks

Comment: @Mat That is my fault. There was a bug in my original answer. I have updated it so it should be correct. I recommend that you read more about `Object.entries()` to understand how it works. You should also read about destructuring syntax to understand the difference between `(brand, checked)` and `[brand, checked]`.

Comment: im now getting: Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [string, boolean], index: number, array: [string, boolean][]) => ReactNode'.
  Type 'any[]' provides no match for the signature '(value: [string, boolean], index: number, array: [string, boolean][]): ReactNode' and then Cannot find name 'brand'.

Comment: @Mat Will you post a new question with the current version of your code and the full error message? Feel free to ping me here with a link and I'll take a look.

Comment: I got it, you missed extra brackets in the answer, I got it working by: map(([brand, checked])=> ...

Comment: if you can just change it for anyone in the future thanks for your help

Comment: @Mat Done. This is what I get for writing code from memory without checking it.

Comment: @Mat If you are interested in understanding why this is the correct syntax, read about lambda functions and destructuring syntax. We are using a combination of both of these here.

Comment: @Mat When you have a single parameter with a lambda function, you don't have to include the `()` around them. I was assuming we didn't need it with the destructured list, either.

Comment: ill read up on it so I understand it more for future thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value of the checkbox to be the value of each key in Brands. i.e. `Brands[brand]`

If you access the value via dot notation, `Brands.brand`, it treats `brand` as a string and literally try searching for a brand named `brand`.

Since you are looping through the brand name in the array, you only know the actual brand like `NewBalance` or `Adidas` in the runtime so you need to use the Bracket Notation `Brands[brand]` so that `brand` is treated as a variable inside the bracket.

```
<input type="checkbox" name={brand} className="cursor-pointer" checked={brandState.Brands[brand]} />
```

Comment: Hi i tried setting it to that but im getting an error of: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type.